# Trying to work out why I can't get into my old open VPN network at my new house

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn

I had a VPN setup at my old house where I could connect to my Banana Pi running OpenVPN from anywhere in the world. I moved house and got a new router which, as far as I can tell, is set up in exactly the same way in terms of opening port 1194 for both UDP and TCP.

When I try and connect from my [Mageia Linux] laptop over the existing VPN set-up it just tells me the attempt times out.

I have looked at the OpenVPN logs on the Pi, but can't see any attempt from the outside world for any connection attempt.

This leads me to believe it's some kind of issue with the router, which is a Zyxel VMG8924-B10A. However, I can't find any way of having the router give me any sort of indication at all as to what traffic is coming in.

So, I am wondering whether there is any way of getting any feedback from the computer I am using to try to connect to the VPN? ie My laptop and not the Pi. I have looked for /var/log/openvpn but that or anything similar does not exist.

Also, longer shot, should a router have logs of incoming attempts to get through an open port? I have looked on the logs page of the router and tried every single category but no logs appear at all.

I'd like to stress that the only thing that's changed here is the router. Banana Pi and laptop are unaltered and my IP address was taken across to the new house.

Many thanks.

Comment: Just curious, what is the point of having a VPN on your own network? Wouldn't you want it on a network not connected to you in any way? I guess unless your just using it to bypass country blocks.

Comment: Are you trying to test your VPN via your public-facing IP, from inside the LAN behind the router? If so, that could be your problem (the new modem may not/probably does not support 'hairpin NAT').  Try accessing it from a computer that's actually outside of your network.

Comment: @Techie. No, I have tethered to my phone so using mobile Internet, definitely not from inside my own network and this method I have used many times in the past.

Comment: @Cam, I don't think you understand what I'm trying to do. I have a Banana Pi on my home [office] network. I want to connect to it when away from home [office]. I used to do this very successfully at the old home with the old router. New home and router just will not work with what I think is an identical setup (but clearly isn't quite identical).